# od output is confusing

Tags: bash

This isn't a deploy related question, but I believe it belongs here.

I've found out about the `od` tool yesterday, and began to fiddle with it.

The question is about `utf-8` encoding. See the examples:

```
~ $ echo -n á | od -x
0000000 a1c3
0000002
~ $ echo -n áá | od -x
0000000 a1c3 a1c3
0000004
~ $ echo -n ác | od -x
0000000 a1c3 0063
0000003

# This is the issue
~ $ echo -n cá | od -x
0000000 c363 00a1
0000003
```

So `á` translates to `c3 a1` correctly in each test besides the last, which begins with an `ascii` char. Why isn't the output of the last test `0063 a1c3` (i.e. invert the one before the last) ?

I've tried to read from a `utf-8` file and the result is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

It's because of endianess of output.

There is an option `--endian` which by default is `little`.

The example string was `cá`, which translates to `63 C3 A1` `utf-8` encoded:

```
~ $ echo -n cá | od --endian=big -x
0000000 63c3 a100
0000003
```

(The `-n` prevents `\n` in the end of string, making last byte `00`)

So it's exactly the same output, but with bytes inverted:

```
~ $ echo -n cá | od --endian=little -x
0000000 c363 00a1
0000003
```

(`c363` instead of `63c3` and so forth).

Answer (score 1):

Because of endianess and other things I've settled on these two aliases I use all the time.  The important thing is `-t x1`

```
alias od1='od -Ax -t x1'
alias od2='od -Ax -t x1 -c'
```

Comment: `-Ax` is for accepting hex offsets in params right ? But then, the `od2`'s `-c` means `-t c` and overrides `-t x1`, so `od2` could just be `od -Ax -c`.

Comment: You might like this better:  `od -ctx1`.  Or use `hexdump -C` (maybe available via `hd`), or `xxd`.  To answer the implied question in the post's title:  "Yes, it is".

Comment: @Niloct `-Ax` is to output the file offsets in hex.  `-t x1` doesn't  negate the `-c` although I see why you would think that.